# Is there a way to obtain the location and file name of where a value is initialized in Rust?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to obtain the location and file name of where a value is initialized in Rust?  I'm aware of the `file!` and `line!` macros, but they provide information of where they're originally called and I'm looking to determine this information from where the value is initialized.  For example, the following code does not work, but is similar to what I'd like:

```rust
// Contains a value as well as where this value was initialized
struct Foo {
    value : usize,
    file : String,
    line : u32,
}
impl Foo {
    fn new(value : usize) -> Foo {
        Foo {
            value,
            file : String::from(std::file!()),
            line : std::line!(),
        }
    }
}

// Test the result
fn main() {
    let foo1 = Foo::new(0);
    println!("foo1 created in file \"{}\" line {}",foo1.file,foo1.line);
    let foo2 = Foo::new(1);
    println!("foo2 created in file \"{}\" line {}",foo2.file,foo2.line);
}
```

This returns

```
foo1 created in file "src/main.rs" line 12
foo2 created in file "src/main.rs" line 12
```

which doesn't contain the correct line number of the value creation.  I'm also trying to do this as transparently as possible, so that the macro doesn't need to typed out by the user for each value created.  As for why, I'm trying to insert some debugging information into a code and it would be helpful for the user to know where in the code the value was created.

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you define your own procedural macro (and even then its iffy since it would be hard to find types in other crates and defined by macros). What do you need this functionality for? When a panic is performed, it should occur at the problem area to help the user find the issue. If you defined a separate function to perform the panic, you may want to consider converting it to a macro instead.

Comment: It's for debugging and the problem is that a panic will give the location of the panic, which is not where the value is instantiated.  I'm looking at an automatic differentiation code.  In the code, a value may be differentiable or not, but it doesn't really matter unless the user asks for a derivative of that value.  For example, `abs(0)` gives a valid value, but it's not differentiable.  As such, the panic would be thrown during derivative processing, but then the user doesn't know where in the code the problem occurred. They'd only know where in the derivative processing, which is less help

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you completely, but it sounds like you want to show where in the function being differentiated the error occurred, not where in the code it gets defined. I suppose this would be easier to implement by returning an `Err(x)` instead of a panic in such a way that as the error travels up the call stack, the surrounding context can be added to `x`. Then once the user unwraps the error, you could have a custom `Debug` implementation to highlight the portion with the issue.

Comment: Yes, I think there's a misunderstanding. I need where the original value instantiation occurs. Try this. Imagine a code where we create a sorted set of values represented as a tree. We start with an empty set and then add new values with the syntax `set.insert(x)`. Now, we can add any value and that's not an error.  However, if we call `set.process()`, we want to throw an error if the set contains any, say, zeros. In that error, we want to know where `set.insert(0)` occurred, but don't really care where `set.process()` occurred. A normal panic or error, gives the latter. I want the former.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by marking the function with the [`#[track_caller]`](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/backend/implicit-caller-location.html) attribute and using [`std::panic::Location::caller()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/panic/struct.Location.html#method.caller) instead of the `file!()` and `line!()` macros. This was originally designed for printing the location of panics, but it doesn't seem to be limited to that context.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a6f054d175c592aa10997fbf11a1102e)